# Numbering grid cells using ABC & 123 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, vector-grid, grids-graticules, numbering

I'm trying to number a grid from 120 rows by 120 columns: horizontal ABC, vertical 123 using Algorithm ID: `'native:creategrid'` and
Algorithm ID: `'QgisregularPoint'`.

Numbering vertically isn't a problem. Numbering horizontally using `is. Numbers` should become characters.

I use:

```
char(65 + ("hor"%26)) || char(65 + round("hor"/26, 0))
```

thinking that if `"hor" == 13`, the result should be `NA` but it gives me `NB`.

I cannot find out what I am doing wrong. Take a look at the table:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `round()` use the [`floor()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#floor) function:

```
char(65 + ("hor"%26)) || char(65 + floor("hor"/26))
```

It will always round down the result, which is what you want in your case.